# Behaviour of Javascript global object when it references the html element in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm a little bit confused about the behaviors of the below javascript code.

-I created a global array object to hold all the anchors

-Then after getting new html from server I update the same in the div

-The html has updated anchor elements

-After the html is replaced I assumed the global would not have modified but it has modified. i.e if i do anc.html() I will get blank output. Why havent anchor references not lost and only its children gone?

-And it empty outs in **IE** and not in **chrome**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var linkArray;
        function setGlobalVar() {
            linkArray = $('.links');
        }
        function iterateGlobalVar() {
            for (var i = 0; i < linkArray.length; i++) {
                var item = $(linkArray[i]);
                alert(item.html());
            }
        }
        function modifyDivHtml() {
            var div1 = $('#div1');
            var html = '<a href="#" class="links"><img src="11.jpg" alt="11" />11</a>';
            div1.html(html);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="setGlobalVar()" value="setGlobalVar--CLICK 1" />

    <div id="div1">
        <a href="#" class="links"><img src="1.jpg" alt="1" />1</a>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="iterateGlobalVar()" value="iterateGlobalVar--CLICK 2" />
    <input type="button" onclick="modifyDivHtml()" value="modifyDivHtml--CLICK 3" />
    <input type="button" onclick="iterateGlobalVar()" value="again iterateGlobalVar--CLICK 4" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I voted to close this. It isn't clear what you are asking here.

Comment: What is lost? What doesn't work? What is "as expected"? What buttons do you click in which order to reproduce this?

Comment: Why are you replacing the entire contents of `#div1` instead of just updating the `src` and `alt` attributes of the image inside?

Comment: Of course you lose the reference. Your collection refers to the element that has been replaced. Each object is unique in the DOM.

Comment: The above code is just a POC and the buttons clearly have the clicking sequences in it. Yes, its refrencing the DOM directly but why it works in Chrome ?

Comment: This might have something to do with [jQuery implementation](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.1&fn=jQuery.fn.html). It's possible, that it uses `append` instead of setting `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Teemu: Not when `value` is a string, though? And still, it should not affect the DOM elements in `linkArray`

Comment: @Bergi You're right (like always ; )). I created two fiddles ([VanillaJS](http://jsfiddle.net/kN36j/2/) and [jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/8z757/1/)) to study this in some browsers, and the results were somewhat strange.

Comment: @Bergi is this something specific to JQuery? Because your test with innerHTML gives result same in IE and Chrome both.